# Best solution for public shop

Tags: ubercart

I want to create a site where users can sell their products.

How best to do this kind of system?

Is it a good idea to use Ubercart or it may be better to use something else?

Comment: Sorry, but any question asking for the 'best' of something is never likely to last long on a Stack Exchange site - it's just too opinion-based, and we need questions to be answerable objectively. The two e-commerce solutions currently are Ubercart and Drupal Commerce, to find out which is best for your own needs you need to do some reading about their features, install them, and actually use them to see if they're what you want

Comment: To add to what @Clive said, this question is also too broad: Whenever it is better to use the Ubercart module or another one depends from your requirements, but you didn't listed them. If you were to ask if it is possible to do something with Ubercart, that would be a better question, after you looked for an answer yourself, and reports what you found out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have got two options. [Ubercart](https://drupal.org/project/ubercart) or [Drupal commerce](https://drupal.org/project/commerce) With Ubercart you have to do some bits of configuration to get your store ready.

With commerce, you have a basic store setup for you if you use the [Commerce kickstart distribution](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_kickstart).

> Commerce Kickstart is the quickest way to get up and running with
>   Drupal Commerce. It includes the latest versions of Drupal core,
>   Drupal Commerce, and the other modules it depends on. It also gives
>   you a set of options to create a fully-featured demo store out of the
>   box complete with an attractive theme, catalog and search
>   configuration, and a custom back office interface.
>
> Who should use Commerce Kickstart? Anyone who wants to skip weeks of
>   configuration to build a commerce site on the Drupal Commerce
>   framework.